# If condition on text width

Tags: conditionals, width

I need to create an ``if clause" based on the length of the subtitle. My code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\subtitle{Testing the Subtitles}
\newlength{\sbtw}\settowidth{\sbtw}{\insertsubtitle}

\ifnum \sbtw > 100
 \newlength{\nyl}\settowidth{\nyl}{\hspace*{100 pt}}
\else 
 \newlength{\nyl}\settowidth{\nyl}{\hspace*{0 pt}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Length of subtitle=\the\sbtw

The value to be assigned is = 0

But the actual assigned value is=\the\nyl
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

But the if clause is not working, and I figured out that the subtitle length command (\sbtw) prints the length in "pt", hence the "ifnum" command is not working. My attempts using numbers (shown below) made the clause working, but I cannot use the numbers directly, because they are to be measured from the text.

```
 \ifnum 94.687 > 100
 \newlength{\nyl}\settowidth{\nyl}{\hspace*{100 pt}}
\else 
 \newlength{\nyl}\settowidth{\nyl}{\hspace*{0 pt}}
\fi
```

My efforts to remove the "pt" from the measured length (using "strip@pt\length") and putting that in the if-condition gives errors.

Any suggestion to solve this would be highly useful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `\ifdim`, not `\ifnum` since you want to check a `dimension`... so `\ifdim\sbtw > 100pt ...\else...\fi`

Comment: why would you do `\settowidth{\nyl}{\hspace*{100 pt}}` rather than `\setlength{\nyl}{100 pt}` ?

Comment: @David, I am still in the learning stage of tex. Thank you very much for your suggestion.